# Unable to left align text on <input type="file">

Tags: css, input

Input with file upload button is:

```css
input[type="file"] {
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #b5bcc7;
  width: 360px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

input[type="file"]::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  background: #485dc5;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 38px;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  border: none;
  float: right;
  ;
}
```

```html
<div> <label for="fileOTHER">File:</label> <input maxsize="255" size="20" onbeforeeditfocus="return false;" type="file" name="file" id="fileOTHER"> </div>
```

But for unknown reason, the text is not moving to the left. It's even overriding the download button. Screenshot:

[image]

Can anyone help on how to move the text towards the left? I am targeting this on Google Chrome with pure css.

Comment: please add more html @Athar K

Comment: There is already a label as you can see 'File:' is inside that label just before this input. I cannot even add any div or label because its not a normal website its a digital system on which I am applying some css stuff.

Comment: add the text align left to outer label

Comment: <div>
<label for="fileOTHER">File:</label>
<input maxsize="255" size="20" onbeforeeditfocus="return false;" type="file" name="file" id="fileOTHER">
</div>

Comment: That's only changing that label alignment.

Comment: then where is the text added "Extract URLS added...." ?

Comment: Its a file name when selected after pressing Choose File button.

Comment: The problem is, when I remove the float: right from -webkit-file-upload-button, the button come to the left and fits the input area perfectly. But I want the other way round to move the button to the right and the text to the left.

Comment: Please Post the rest of your code

Comment: The code is in total. The input field and the css I have applied. Nothing else is there.

Comment: Where does the form framework come from in your pic?

Comment: all you have is an input are you trying to achieve desired results in pic

Comment: where is your title input and form at?

Comment: Its a system. The form is being generated dynamically having this input field. I need to work on this input so that's just I shared. No need to share the whole form.

Comment: @Jonny, click the Run code snippet button. See how the placeholder text is in the middle? The OP wants it left-aligned.

Comment: Thanks @MikeMcCaughan.

Answer (score 2):

You can use direction rtl to display the input from right to left instead of left to right.  Hope it helps

```css
input[type="file"] {
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #b5bcc7;
  width: 360px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  direction: rtl;
}



input[type="file"]::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  background: #485dc5;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 38px;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  border: none;
  float: right;
  
}
```

```html
<div> <label for="fileOTHER">File:</label> <input maxsize="255" size="20" onbeforeeditfocus="return false;" type="file" name="file" id="fileOTHER"> </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer though it's not the requirement. I need to start the text from the left.

Comment: so you need it aligned left but set up like i have it?

Comment: Yes exactly. But the rtl thing inverts the text. I need text normal as well.

Comment: Check my answer Jonny & @MikeMcCaughan.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone seeking similar thing, here is the solution.

```css
input[type="file"] {
    margin-left: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #b5bcc7;
    width: 250px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    outline: none;
}

input[type="file"]::-webkit-file-upload-button {
    background: #485dc5;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 38px;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    border: none;
    width: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: none;
  
}

x::-webkit-file-upload-button, input[type=file]:after {
    content:'Choose File';
    display: inline-block;
    left: 100%;
    margin-left:0px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
}

input[type=file]:after {
    margin-left: 0px;
    background: #485dc5;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 38px;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    border: none;
    outline: 1px solid #485dc5;
}
```

```html
<div> <label for="fileOTHER">File:</label> <input maxsize="255" size="20" onbeforeeditfocus="return false;" type="file" name="file" id="fileOTHER"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
input[type=file]{
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #b5bcc7;
  width: 360px;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 38px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

input[type="file"]::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  background: #485dc5;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 38px;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  margin-right:0;
  border: none;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="files">
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).